# Problems with referencing file name and content with React-uploady component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use react-uploady library. Here is my main component:

```
<Uploady
          // debug
          destination={{ url: '/s3createObject', headers: {'filekey': nodePath[nodePath.length-1].Key + props.file.name, 
                                                            'accept': '*.jpg'},
                                                  params : {'body': uploadBody}} }
          >
          <UploadyButton></UploadyButton>
          <PreviewsContainer>
            <UploadPreview rememberPreviousBatches PreviewComponent={QueueItem} />
          </PreviewsContainer>
        </Uploady>
```

I am unable to figure out how do i reference the file name and content of the current file being uploaded. I will need to pass those details to my server end point (in the params).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue but I only needed the filename, used useRequestPreSend to send the data to the server. It's in their docs [here](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady/blob/master/guides/DynamicParameters.md)

My component hook looked like this:

```
const UploadContainer = ({ items }) => {
  useRequestPreSend(({ items }) => {
    const documentName = items[0].file.name

    return {
      options: {
        destination : {
          params: {
            document_name: documentName,
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })

...
return (
...
}
```

Uploady component:

```
  <Uploady
    destination={{
      url: url,
      params: {
        "document_name": "",
      }
    }}
    debug="true"
    method="POST"
    multiple={false}
  >
    <UploadDropZone
      className="upload-dropzone"
      onDragOverClassName="drag-over"
      grouped={false}
    >

      <UploadContainer items={props.items} />
    </UploadDropZone>
  </Uploady>
```

Comment: great answer. notice that youd want to switch off the debug flag in production env